# Framework7 production or development env inside the app

Tags: webpack, html-framework-7

I'm building a proof of concept level mobile app with Framework7. I'm not too familiar with the building environments (webpack in this case), but since this is a poc and not not a production level app, I think that's ok.

So I'd need to konw how to detect if the app was build with development or with production environment, in order to configure correct address for the backend server requests within my ajax code.

Is there a way to get this inside the Framework7 app? I tried `console.log(process.env)` within app.js but it was undefined.

I've found a few questions with a lot of webpack specific terminology, that unfortunately do not understand.

I'm using out of the box Framework7 with webpack build env. No Vue or React.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks for being my rubber duck. The default Framework7 installation gives out webpack config that then allows me to `console.log ( process.env.NODE_ENV );` within the app.